# ntdll.pdb not loaded -- unable to find

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, pdb-files

I'm working in Visual Studio 2017 (Windows 10). I'm trying to develop with the OpenSSL-Bio-Fetch source code from https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client.
I wind up hitting an error and am unable to debug through it due to it not finding the ntdll.pdb.
I get the following message:

[image]

I've been able to find lots of pdb files, but none that match. They are all different versions. This one seems to be:
10.0.14393.1532 (rs1_release_d.170711-1840)

I've also tried to pull the .lib/.dll/.pdb from a different Windows machine, but can't get VS to recognize it.

1- Anyone know where I can find the correct PDB?
2- Anyone able to point me how to get the proper ntdll.lib/.dll/.pdb placed so that VS will use it?

Comment: One of the lines says *"C:\Symbols\ntdll.pdb Access denied"*. You might want to look into the access rights.